# Backbone belongs_to has_many

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, backbone-relational

Longtime Rails Dev, Backbone Noob.

In my rails models, a project has many tasks and a task belongs to a project.. Standard stuff.

Trying to get a project's tasks json in a collection.

```
ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/projects/<dynamic_id>/tasks',
  model: ExampleApp.Models.Task
});
```

Every example Ive seen so far references the url as /tasks. Id like to pass a project id to the collection to get that projects tasks.

Ive checked out [Backbone Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) but not sure what the best solution is.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend using Backbone-Relational as opposed to hacking the relationship on your own. Reasons for using Backbone-Relational from personal experience:

- Creates forward and backward relationships, so you can get all tasks related to a project, or the project to which a task belongs
- Easy to serialize, and automatic deserizalization. That is, you give it a JSON and it builds out all the models and their relationships. Very handy.
- Your models remain independently defined and can use standard Backbone stuff to save/fetch without any additional work.
- It can also play nicely with various Backbone extensions such as [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) and [ioBind/ioSync](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind).

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define *url* as a function and set your project_id prior to fetch()

```
ExampleApp.Collections.Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ExampleApp.Models.Task

    url: function() {
        return 'projects/'+this.project_id+'/tasks';
    },

    setProjectId(project_id) {
        this.project_id = project_id;
        this.fetch();
    }
});
```